# Minimum hardware to boot into BIOS

Tags: boot, motherboard

Are the RAM module or CPU required to boot the motherboard? What is the minimal configuration to boot into BIOS? The motherboard I need to boot is a mediocre ASUS socket LGA775.

Comment: Do you want to configure the BIOS? Or just boot into the BIOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes CPU and RAM is needed to boot up into the BIOS config utility if you meant this. Also a VGA, PSU... and that's it I guess.

(And if you may want to enter to the BIOS, a keyboard comes handy. :-))

Comment: And the motherboard itself ;) A keyboard would be useful as well.

Comment: **No keyboard detected. Press F1 to continue.**

Comment: Hey hey you dont need those to boot! :-D But yeah got a point.

Comment: Powercord. Don't forget the powercord.