# What is the minimum amount of parts needed to get a beep code out of a PC?

Tags: hardware-failure

When attempting to verify if either the motherboard or CPU is defective by connecting only the power supply and CPU to the motherboard, does a lack of a beep code imply that the motherboard is defective, or is a working CPU necessary for a beep code?

*Note: the speaker and PSU were tested in a different, working PC and verified to be be working correctly.*

Comment: You mention "speaker" in your note, but specifically say you connected "only PSU, motherboard, and cpu". Where is this speaker? is it plugged into the speaker jack, or is it a "PC internal speaker" connected to a jumper on the mainboard? Some mainboards will emit signals throuigh the speaker jack, other will not, so check the manual to ensure your speaker is connected in a way that will cause the speaker to emit sounds.

Comment: The *Power-On Self Tests*, aka POST, beep codes typically require a CPU to execute the BIOS routines.  However, one site claimed that there were some Intel mobos that did not require a CPU.  IMO it seems extravagant to have a microcontroller solely for power-up tests that then becomes superfluous when the CPU is installed (the normal situation).  And of course you need a PSU to provide electrical power.

Comment: @horatio The speaker is connected. I was trying not to make the question too specific by drawing it out. My main concern is whether we should be considering the CPU to be defective since we got a replacement motherboard that the company assured us was operational.

Comment: If you do not have sophisticated test gear for specific devices, substitution is the best (and thorough) way to test functionality.  Seems like you have substituted the mobo already.  Substituting the CPU would be the final step to confirm your suspicions (and validate the original mobo).  BTW be sure to use anti-static techniques to avoid damaging electronic components.

Comment: @Koviko: "The speaker is connected." My question was "how is it connected." In some main boards, the BEEP codes will simply not be heard by speakers plugged into a speaker jack: one must use an "internal PC speaker" attached to the mainboard using a jumper (often near the PWR and HDDLED case jumpers) labeled "SPK." This varies by manufacturer and by date of manufacture

Comment: @sawdust: I am not so sure regarding CPU, most schemes have a beep code for CPU failure which implies that a CPU is not required

Comment: @horatio You could give us a little more credit than that.

Comment: Are you refusing to clarify?

Comment: @horatio It's a silly assumption that we'd test the speaker on a separate PC and somehow have no idea where to connect it on the other motherboard. Yes, I'm refusing to clarify where clarification is extraneous.

Comment: So this other PC was an identical mainboard?

Comment: @horatio The question is answerable as is. Please stop asking questions about the speaker.

Comment: @horatio - The chassis/case/motherboard speaker was replaced by a piezo buzzer at least 10 years ago by most manufacturers.  *"...implies that a CPU is not required"* - Since that code is not well documented, it's hard so say what it represents.  But I'd guess that it's a CPU selftest.  Basic computer architecture predicts that no CPU means no POST beep codes from the BIOS.  Maybe there are a few mobos that have extra logic to emit a beep code for a missing/failed CPU.  But that logic is not likely to perform a full POST.

Comment: @sawdust: Nobody should expect "a full POST" without a CPU. The problem here is that the question is asked with a very low specificity and the POST tests, capabilities, and inbuilt speaker design vary greatly between manufacturer and even mainboard. The OP also points out obliquely that the speaker in removable (not piezo). As an example: Some Intel boards report a 1-5-2-1 beep code for "missing cpu slot1" and 1-5-2-2 "No Processors".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you need what you have: a motherboard, a CPU and a PSU.

IME, I have never found a desktop motherboard that will beep if there's no CPU.

In almost all cases, if cooling is attached properly and if the PSU tests OK, it's the motherboard.

Also see: [Minimum hardware to boot into BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/150767/minimum-hardware-to-boot-into-bios)

Comment: I agree with you regarding the CPU and beeps, but "DrDave" disagrees: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110824202446AAdDPe6  Wonder if there are any YouTube videos?